# Parallel execution of cmake functions?

Tags: cmake

When running cmake on a large project, can it call a given cmake function in parallel?

What I am concerned about is that when this (user defined) function stores something in the cache then that would collide with the parallel execution; how does cmake deal with this when functions are indeed executed in parallel, or do I have to make sure that even invocations of the same function will never use the same (cached) variable name with different values?

EDIT (see comments):

I wrote the following function,

```
function(CW_SYS_CACHELINE_SIZE)
  if (NOT DEFINED CACHE{cw_cv_sys_cacheline_size})
    set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION "Release")
    try_run(RUN_WORKS
            COMPILE_WORKS
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cw_utils_sys_cacheline_size
            ${CW_SYS_CACHELINE_SIZE_MODULE_PATH}/CW_SYS_CACHELINE_SIZE.c
            COMPILE_OUTPUT_VARIABLE COMPILE_OUTPUT
            RUN_OUTPUT_VARIABLE RUN_OUTPUT)
    if (NOT COMPILE_WORKS)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to compile test program 
CW_SYS_CACHELINE_SIZE.c: ${COMPILE_OUTPUT}")
    elseif (NOT RUN_WORKS EQUAL 0)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to run test program CW_SYS_CACHELINE_SIZE.c: ${RUN_OUTPUT}")
    else ()
      set(cw_cv_sys_cacheline_size ${RUN_OUTPUT} CACHE INTERNAL "")
    endif ()
  endif()
endfunction()
```

Since this function doesn't take arguments, the internal values of the used variables are expected to be the same every time; but I have other very similar functions that do almost the exact same thing, except that they compile and test a different `.c` file.

So, each of those functions can have a different value of `RUN_WORKS`, which is (as it turns out) written to the cache as `INTERNAL`. Suppose that I am not terminating the program but doing something else with the value of `RUN_WORKS` here. Then it could be that I first run this function where `RUN_WORKS` is true, and then run the other function which sets `RUN_WORKS` to false.

If then I run cmake again (or inadvertently call the first function again),
then it has no way of knowing if the current value of `RUN_WORKS` in the cache has anything to do with a previous run of THIS function (and/or with the same arguments, if it has some). So, it CANNOT use the value of the cached variable. BUT - cmake *is* caching it. This worries me; why would it be caching anything if it isn't planning to reuse its value later? I'd feel a lot better if it didn't cache these variables.

So, my reasoning was: if anything is being cached (`INTERNAL` or not) I must make sure it is 100% unique (aka, that cmake will always write the same value to the same variable, or it wouldn't have made sense to cache it in the first place). But how to do that with this `RUN_WORKS` variable? I'm just horribly confused about how to write safe code like this :/

Comment: I don't think I follow.. cmake scripts are __not__ executed concurently, cmake scripts are executed sequentially. Cmake does not "deal" with functions executed in parallel, because he doesn't execute them in parallel. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, if you are certain... I read namely somewhere that parallel execution DOES happen (I suppose to speed up things). And why not? Theoretically it would be possible. The only reason I can think of that this will never happen is when it is explicitly documented that all of cmake execution is single threaded.

Comment: It happens at build stage and when executing multiple commands in execute_process. Both those things aren't functions and not modify the cache. `And why not?` - because cmake is not about speed, it is supposed to be run once.

Comment: Maybe consider switching your build system e.g. https://bazel.build/ - runs in parallel even on a cluster

Comment: @KamilCuk Ok, I updated my question explaining why it worries me that certain variables that are only "locally" set and then used (and then could be discarded) are not unique: cmake does cache them. Why??

Comment: @Vertexwahn I'm switching from autotools to cmake since a couple of days (I'm new to cmake thus). The reason I switch to cmake is because according to other professionals cmake is the currently THE industry standard for building (C++) projects. I never heard of bazel before. This is not about that cmake would have defects, it is about how popular it is. If you look at cmake documentations and/or talks, it is incredibly simple (as well). In practice it never is as I'm rapidly discovering. I'm sure basel won't be the magic holy grail either :p.

Comment: I would advise to keep a convention where normal result variables are lower case and exported variables are uppercase.

Comment: That doesn't address the issue though.

Comment: So you are not worried about parallel execution. You are worried about the _next sequential_ execution of cmake configuration stage and using two try_run with the same vairable names, right? But that `try_run` caches the variables, it doesn't mean it will use them. (out of curiosity, why do you want to know the cacheline size?)

Comment: `try_run` caches the variables, but doesn't use them. Your "reasoning" is based that if something is cached it it later used, it is not. The [commit that introduced caching the result](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/202600f95a2fe3c401e7c6ba64a3ce93e2143f88#diff-638f21b0e19ecab72aeed7410e972157) is 17 years old, I could believe it was used back then for something. I don't see in [RunExecutable](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmTryRunCommand.cxx#L165) how the cache is used, it's just ignored.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ok, thank you for you kind help and investigation of the matter. I am now assuming that the 'cache' is needed to transfer the result of the try_run function to the caller (output variables), because try_run (someone else told me) is a builtin function and does not create a scope: PARENT_SCOPE can't be used here. That, combined with that cmake does not run functions in parallel, then makes it 'safe'. I need to know the cache line size to put certain atomics far enough apart in memory to be decoherent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... can it call a given CMake function in parallel?

No, **configuration** stage of CMake, when it processes `CMakeLists.txt` and, among other things, executes its functions, is performed strictly **sequentially**.

Only **build** stage, when libraries and executables are compiled and COMMAND's (in `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target`) are executed can be performed in parallel.

Moreover, during the *build* stage CMake isn't running at all: this stage is controlled by the build tool, selected as a [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) for CMake.